# Identification of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

I am given an inclusion of vector spaces $L \subseteq V$ and I know that $V^{\vee \vee} = W^\vee$ for some vector space $W$. There are no assumptions of finite dimensionality. Through the inclusion
$$ L \subseteq V \subseteq  V^{\vee \vee} = W^\vee$$
I can define
$$L_0:= \{w \in W \mid \forall \ \ell \in L, \ \ell(w) = 0 \}.$$
Under the assumption that $L_0$ is finite dimensional, I would like to show that $V/L \cong L_0^\vee$ canonically. Any hints?

**Remark:** It must be crucial that $L_0$ is finite dimensional. For instance, for $L=0$ and $V$ infinite dimensional we would have
$$V/L=V \subsetneq V^{\vee\vee} = L_0^\vee = W^\vee.$$

**Attempt 1:** I have been trying to use the fact that for every inclusion $A \subseteq B$ of vector spaces, we always have

$$ A^\vee \cong B^\vee / A^{\bot_B}, \quad A^{\bot_B} \cong (B/A)^\vee,$$

where $A^{\bot_B}:=\{ \phi \in B^\vee \mid \forall \ a \in A, \ \phi(a) = 0\}$, so in my case I could write something like
$$ L_0^\vee \cong W^\vee / L_0^{\bot_W} = V^{\vee\vee} / L_0^{\bot_W},$$
but I am not sure whether this helps at all.

**Attempt 2:** We have
$$ L_0 \cong L^{\bot_{W^\vee}} \cap W \subseteq W^{\vee \vee},$$
but also this line of thought did not bring me anywhere.

Comment: What is $\vee$ and $\perp_X$ supposed to mean?

Comment: $\vee$ is the dual space (sometimes denoted $*$), and $\bot_X$ is defined in the question

Comment: The $X$ in $\bot_X$ keeps track of the ambient space, as the same vector space can be seen as a subspace of various vector spaces

Comment: @57Jimmy: Isn't your assumption $V^{\vee \vee} = W^{\vee}$ just means that $W = V^{\vee}$? Then $L_0$ is just $L^{\perp}$ and you have a natural isomorphism $(V / L)^{\vee} \cong L^{\perp}$. Since you assume $L^{\perp}$ is finite dimensional, the dual of the natural isomorphism gives us an isomorphism between $(V / L)$ and $(L^{\perp})^{\vee}$.

Comment: @levap Thanks for your comment. I'd like this to be true, but I don't think that I can assume that $W = V^\vee$, since $V$ and $W$ are not finite dimensional

Comment: Actually, even though I am not sure whether I can assume it in general, it might be true in my specific case that $V^\vee = W$. That would indeed solve the problem then, and what I wanted to prove might not be true in the general case. Thanks then!

Comment: @57Jimmy: Well, think about what $V^{\vee \vee} = W^{\vee}$ means. As a set, an element $\varphi$ of $V^{\vee \vee}$ is a linear functional $\varphi \colon V^{\vee} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$. If $V^{\vee \vee} = W^{\vee}$ then surely $\varphi \in W^{\vee}$ but then $\varphi$ is also a linear functional $\varphi \colon W \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ and then we must have $W = V^{\vee}$ as sets. I suspect that what you mean by "$V^{\vee \vee} = W^{\vee}$" is not literally an equality but the notion of a perfect pairing but you need to be more precise in order to be able to prove something.

Comment: @levap I meant that I have a canonical identification $V^{\vee \vee} \cong W^\vee$. I see your point, but why is it true that $$X^\vee \cong Y^\vee \Rightarrow X\cong Y?$$In any case, as I mentioned above, your remark helped me realize that I had some redundancy in my problem, having written $V^{\vee \vee} = W^\vee$ when I actually already knew that $V^\vee = W$ in my situation. So the problem is solved. Thanks again.